# Compute a row in Pandas operating other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this-

```
df = pd.DataFrame{"a":[2.22, 3.444, 4.3726],"b":[3.44, 5.96, 7.218] }
```

I need to compute another column c by the following operation on column a-

```
c = len(str(a))-len(str(int(a)))-1
```

Tried different methods but not able to achieve.

Comment: "Tried different methods" - what exactly did you try? What exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is different digits after `.` is possible use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[2.22, 3.444, 4.3726],"b":[3.44, 5.96, 7.218] })

print (df.a.astype(str).str.len())
0    4
1    5
2    6
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df['c'] = df.a.astype(str).str.len() - df.a.astype(int).astype(str).str.len() - 1
```

But because float precision is problematic count values with general data (simulate problem):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[2.220000000236, 3.444, 4.3726],"b":[3.44, 5.96, 7.218] })
print (df.a.astype(str).str.len())
0    14
1     5
2     6
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution creates column C with the desired result.

```
df['c'] = df['a'].astype(str).str.len() - df['a'].astype(int).astype(str).str.len() - 1
```